# MySQL-Solr for geospatial search

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, geospatial, postgis

The site currently does mainly range searches (latitude & longitude) with some filtering like `WHERE color = "red"` type of clauses. However using MySQL with geospatial index is still quite slow and I need to speed it up.

**Problem:** Will using Solr to do the search be a good idea?

If so, should I only duplicate the range columns from MySQL into Solr, and do the `WHERE` clauses in MySQL, or do both type of queries in Solr?

I've read that Solr is not for storing data like a database (ie. MySQL). Does this mean that if my search can take place over 10 different columns (or `field` in Solr terms), and the MySQL table that I replicated Solr's from only has 11 tables, I would still keep the MySQL table even though that will use up almost twice as much storage space half of which is redundant?

It appears that I'm using structured data (because each row has many columns defined?) and storing the entire table in Solr instead having redundant data on MySQL and Solr will save storage space and number of database access operations when writing. Is Solr a good choice here?

In terms of speed, would it be better to use PostGIS or Solr?

Answer (score 2):

Solr has very fast numerical/date range queries. Solr 3 geospatial takes advantage of that, and I wrote [a plugin](https://github.com/dsmiley/SOLR-2155) that does even better.  I doubt MySQL is faster.

That said, if the sole problem you are trying to solve is slow geospatial queries then bringing in Solr may solve it but will add a lot of overall complexity to your system since it isn't designed to replace relational databases--it works alongside them.  Don't get me wrong; Solr is awesome, particularly for faceted navigation and text search.  But you didn't state you wanted to take advantage of Solr's primary features.

PostGIS is by far the most mature open-source GIS storage system.  I suggest you try it as an experiment to see if it's better.  I would try a lat + lon pair of columns approach like what you are doing now with MySQL, and I would also try using the PostGIS native geospatial way to do it, whatever that is exactly.

One thing you could try in either MySQL or PostGIS is to round your latitude and longitude value to the number of decimals to get an appropriate level of precision you need, which is surely far less than the full precision of a double.  And if you store them in floats rather than doubles, right there the precision is capped to 2.37 meters.  The system you use will probably have a much easier time doing range queries if there are fewer distinct values to scan over.

Comment: By added complexity, do you mean using DIH to sync Solr with MySQL (which will act as the main data store)? Having Solr's data 1 minute behind MySQL is still tolerable in my situation.

Comment: SOLR-2155 looks sweet, will definitely try that out! What I need is fast range search (timestamp and lat/lon pairs) over a table with 500k rows. I do not foresee requiring fulltext search. As for rounding up the lat/lon values, I will also be plotting pins on a map with these lat/lon values. Will a good way be to round up the values when storing in Solr, and use the more accurate values stored in MySQL when plotting the pins on a map?

Comment: You'd probably use the DIH; yeah.  With a measly 500k rows in Solr, don't bother rounding the lat-lon as an optimization.

Comment: Additionally: A big thing to keep in mind is that Solr has a limited data model compared to a relational DB.  No JOINs, and don't try to join on the fly with a database which is asking for a performance problem. Ideally, Solr will be able to completely satisfy the search request you are trying to speed up.  Shameless plug: I wrote the popular Solr book, which you might consider as a resource in addition to Solr's wiki.